# Experience as an initial value problem?

Tags: consciousness, physicalism, neurophilosophy, experience

### Question

The argument seems to say just as I have a physical [initial value problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem) and with the laws of physics tell the time evolution, similarly, I can have an initial value problem of experience and with the different time evolution laws tell you one of the possible experience states one will inhabit in the future.

I don't know what the below argument is known as. And forgive my ignorance for being unaware of the assumptions it makes (I happen to have physics training **not philosophy**).

Could someone could tell me the name of the argument (if it exists) and the assumptions it makes?

### Argument

Let us look at the mappings between the physical configurations of the brain (assume classical mechanics suffices) and the experience state both at a particular point of time (t=0) :

Assume someone is zapping your brain with an electrode to evoke a sensation. Then we can map that physical configuration of the brain (let us call this A) to the sensation one is having (A’)

[image]

Now let’s assume I increase the current by one electron then we have a new brain configuration (B) . Is the brain sensitive to this change? No. Then even B maps to A’. We have many-to-one mapping!
[image]

The Time Evolution

The brain configuration has a one-to-one mapping for each brain configuration at t= 0 with the brain configuration at say t = 1 as a function of the environment. This is a consequence of the laws of physics being equivalent to initial value problems

[image]

A different environment will give rise to a different brain configuration at time t = 1.
Using this we can map back to experience state and thus get a mapping of the time evolution of the experience state.
[image]

Thus we having a many to one mapping of experience (in the sense given the information I know what I am experiencing at time t = 0 then at time t =1 I either E’ or F’)
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry More, I don't understand the question.

Comment: @ScottRowe can you articulate which part is problematic? It would help me fix that part?

Comment: Sorry, I was being flippant... I read through once and didn't see a question, but later realized you are just asking if this form of argument has a name, perhaps so you can study it further. It is hard for me to relate to, as mainly a computer programmer, but my ignorance is often shown to me.

Comment: This sounds the famous epiphenomenalism (a form of property dualism) in philosophy of mind...

Comment: @DoubleKnot what is the epiphenomenal view on death? I doubt my final time evolution law would halt even when the physical brain perishs (A' to E' or F')

Comment: Under epiphenomenalism, death is perhaps a very special and extremely simple moment than other times as there's no epiphenomenal magic to account for...

Comment: @DoubleKnot thanks this is helpful. Would the epiphenomenalist say that the "experience" of death is unique or constant with time? While under my model say one experiences X post death  then depending on the law one obtains a logical possibility would be X to Y as well instead of X to X

Comment: Also any book suggestion for epiphenomenal view on death ?

Comment: There's no logical inconsistency I can spot from your above metaphysical speculation of death under epiphenomenalism. Indeed, this could be some "evidence" support for the perennial afterlife heaven/hell depictions and physical strange anecdotes especially in many religions, though many of them perhaps arrived at similar conclusion via other routes such as idealism... A relevant book from my mind could be the old classic Buddhism [FILIAL PIETY SUTRA](http://www.cttbusa.org/filialpiety/filialpietysutra.htm) where I remember talked in detail about bodies after death and their experiences...

Comment: time is not always a segment with start and end. time can be circle. 
0 and 1 must be set already. If you set 0 predict to 1, you should to set when 1 is predict to 0 also, or why not, or something. Needed contra version.